# Creating a popup in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in ReactJs and trying to create a popup window through onclick event.

I am following this resource - https://dev.to/skptricks/create-simple-popup-example-in-react-application-5g7f

File - `/src/components/feed.js`

```
import React from 'react';

function feed (props) {

    return (
        <div className="card-header">
            <h2>{props.firstname} {props.middleInitial} {props.lastname}</h2>
            <h4 className="card-title">{props.gender}</h4>
        </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
                <button onClick="" className="btn btn-secondary">Click To view Samples</button>
            </div>
    );
}

export default feed;
```

File - `/src/app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import Header from './components/header.js';
import fetchfeed  from './components/fetchfeed.js';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <fetchfeed />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

File - `/src/components/fetchfeed.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import feed  from './feed.js';

class fetchfeed extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        feedDetails: []
    };
    this.fetchURL = this.fetchURL.bind(this);
}

fetchURL() {
   axios.get(`/feed/`)
        .then( response => {
    ..............
    });
 //Fetch the feed url and process the variables and setstate to feedDetails array.
}
componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchURL()
}


populateRowsWithData = () => {
    const feedData = this.state.feedDetails.map(feed => {
        return <feed
            key = {feed.id}
            firstname = {feed.firstname}
            middleInitial = {feed.middleInitial}
            lastname = {feed.lastname}
            dateOfBirth = {feed.dateString}
            gender = {feed.gender}
        />;
    });

    return feedData
}

render(){

    return (
        <div >

            {this.populateRowsWithData()}

        </div>
    );
}

}
export default fetchfeed;
```

I have already created Popup.js under /src/components and the required css for the popup as directed on reference link.
My question is where should I define the onclick function for popup?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the model to show when you click "Click to view samples" button in `feed.js`, you should define your `onClick` function in `feed.js` and attach it to the button.

Comment: How to attach it? I have defined the function in feed.js but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I can't see you have defined any function in `feed.js`. and also the `onClick` attribute of your button is empty.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the source you should do something like this in the component you want to show the popup in:

```
//This is the function
 togglePopup() {  
   this.setState({  
     showPopup: !this.state.showPopup  
   }); 
 }
```

```
// This is what you should do in the render method
{this.state.showPopup ?  
    <Popup  
          text='Click "Close Button" to hide popup'  
          closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}  
    />  
: null  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to customize the code in the tutorial according to your requirements. If you want to open the popup on click of the button "click to view samples", you should do two things first.

- Define a function to trigger when button is clicked
- Attach that function to the button

The following code demonstrates above steps.

```
import React from 'react';

function feed (props) {
    function openPopup(){
      //code relevant to open popup
    }

    return (
        <div className="card-header">
            <h2>{props.firstname} {props.middleInitial} {props.lastname}</h2>
            <h4 className="card-title">{props.gender}</h4>
        </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
                <button onClick={openPopup} className="btn btn-secondary">Click To view Samples</button>
            </div>
    );
}

export default feed;
```